# .NET Core SDK installed, but .NET Core VS2015 won't install? Is it required?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

What exactly is .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2? And is it required for VSCode if you already have .NET Core SDK installed?

I was having issues with a fresh OS install where VSCode kept giving me "Install CLI Tools" errors. I was able to remedy it and get debugging/intellisense by installing .NET Core SDK. Right now VSCode runs flawlessly, but am wondering what exactly the difference between the two is? It won't let me install .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 because it says I need to install Visual Studio 2015. Is it required? What's the purpose of .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS2015 tooling package is for people wanting to compile and debug .NET core code using Visual Studio 2015.

Visual Studio 2015 is an entirely separate product to Visual Studio Code, and this tooling preview package is therefore not required if you are only working with VS Code.